# int or char enum to int , not ASCII

Tags: c++, pointers, enums, char, int

I'm doing a poker game and have hit a wall. Any help would be great.

I have 12 card values.  The values are `char`s either 2-9 or TJQKA (enumed below). I need to pass them to an int array such that their value is what gets passed (whether int value or enum value) instead of their ASCII.

for the example below, I want:

```
val[5] = {2,5,10,12,11}
```

instead of:

```
val[5] = {50,53,84,81,74}
```

```
enum cardvalues {T=10 , J , Q , K , A}
int val[5];


string value = "25TQJ";

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    val[i] = value[i]; 
}
```

Comment: converting string to enum is almost impossible without some serious work, go for a switch statement, it will make your life a lot happier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a conversion function:

```
int to_card(const char v)
{
    switch(v)
    {
    case '2': return 2;
    case '3': return 3:
    // etc...

    case 'T': return 10;
    case 'J': return 11;

    // etc...
}
```

Then in your loop:

```
val[i] = to_card(value[i]);
```

Answer (score 7):

I would highly recommend using a [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map/) rather than an enum.

```
map<char,int> myCardMap;
myCardMap['T'] = 10;
...
val[i] = myCardMap[value[i]];
```

Answer (score 3):

Make an `std::map` with ascii values in key and enum values in value

```
std::map<char, int> asciiMap;
asciiMap['T'] = 10;
asciiMap['J'] = 11;
//etc....
```

and then match the characters with the map

Answer (score 3):

Generally you would need to convert the values from char to int. Here's the easiest way.

```
int convert_from_char(char c) {
   if (c >= '2' && c <= '9') return (int)(c - '0');
   else {
      switch(c) {
         case 'T': return (int)T;
         case 'J': return (int)J;
         case 'Q': return (int)Q;
         case 'K': return (int)K;
         case 'A': return (int)A;
         default:
         /* your program is borked. */
            exit(1);
     }
   }
}
```

Then change your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)  
   val[i] = convert_from_char(value[i]);
```

I would suggest reconsidering using enums to represent cards, though.  It will be easier in the long run just to make your own type, or use integers.

Comment: This seems like a simple version compared to others. Maybe not as good as using Map but.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to *directly* convert from an `enum` symbol to the corresponding integer in C++ at runtime (obviously the compiler can do this at compile time). You may need to write a small helper function:

```
int card_value(char c) {
    if (isdigit(c)) {
        return c - '0';
    } else {
        switch (c) {
            case 'T': return 10;
            case 'J': return 11;
            case 'Q': return 12;
            case 'K': return 13;
            case 'A': return 14;
            default:
                // whatever error handling here, such as:
                return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a switch:

```
switch (value[i]) {
  case '2':  case '3':  case '4':  case '5':  case '6':  case '7':  case '8':  case '9':
    val[i] = atoi(value[i]);
    break;
  case 'T':
    val[i] = 10;
    break;
  case 'J':
    val[i] = 11;
    break;
  case 'Q':
    val[i] = 12;
    break;
  case 'K':
    val[i] = 13;
    break;
  case 'A':
    val[i] = 14;
    break;
  default:
    printf("Invalid character passed\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that will take a char argument (the ASCII card value, such as 'J') and return its numerical value. You might find the isdigit function and switch statement helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If im understanding you correctly, you want to convert the string into card values (although for some reason you have the ace as 13 - id be tempted to say use 1 as the ace, although i can see you logic for it in a poker game).

Just using an enum wont help as at runtime you dont really have the information you need.  An enum is a compile time concept mainly to assist the programmer and to handle checking.

There are many way to do what you want, you could have an array of index to char or a two entry array of char and value.  For ease of alterations i would go with the following

```
typedef struct
{
    char m_cCharacter;
    int  m_nValue;
} LOOKUP;

LOOKUP lookup_data[] = {
    { "2", 2 },
    { "3", 3 },
    { "4", 4 },
    { "5", 5 },
    { "6", 6 },
    { "7", 7 },
    { "8", 8 },
    { "9", 9 },
    { "T", 10 },
    { "J", 11 },
    { "Q", 12 },
    { "K", 13 },
    { "A", 14 }
};

int GetCharacter(char c)
{
     int retval = -1; // Invalid 

     for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
     {
         if ( lookup_data[i].m_cCharacter == c )
         {
              retval = lookup_data[i].m_nValue;
              break;
         }
     }

     return retval;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)        
{
    val[i] = GetCharacter(value[i]);
}
```

There are better ways with STL, and you should have more error checking and length of array detections, but hopefully you get the idea.  You could use the enum in the lookup such as

```
{  "T", T },
```

If you preferred.  Btw - i havent compiled this code so it probably wont build ;)

Comment: Guess i overcomplicated it ;)  A switch would be easier as you are unlikely to want to change / add to the list.  Although I would go for a function with the switch as you will probably want this in a few places.  Have one that takes a character and returns the value and another that takes a value and gives the appropriate character.  That way if you do decide to move the ace to a value of 1, its only a few changes rather than lots throughout the code

Comment: This is c++. A `std::map` does everything you ask in O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Try building a static array of size 256 such that the following gives the right answer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    val[i] = AsciiToInt[value[i]]; 
}
```

That is,

```
AsciiToInt['2'] == 2
AsciiToint['T'] == 10,
AsciiToInt['J'] == 11
```

etc, but all invalid entries are zero.